# how to concat the value without comma in a column without spliting in csv file

Tags: java

how to solve this number "1,234.50" ?
I only like to remove the comma (i.e) 1234.50 I want this number in single column. this number shouldn't be splitted into next column in CSV file.

Is there is any code for that?
can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the relevant code from your program which is handling this number and writing the CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Best and indeed only way is to create a new String containing the value you want.
You can use a regular expression for that, or split the original on the comma and then build a new String from the resulting bits and pieces.

Comment: i m having this value in my csv file.... i m going to preprocessing that by removing commas in each column of that csv file. Though csv file is a comma separator file... while splitting by comma this value comma is also splitting... i don't like to split this value which is mentioned above